# How to pass component data object to a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, pipe, refactoring

**Background**
On a project I am working on, I have a generic collection-filtering pipe, that...well...filters collections.  It's used most prominently in Material Design Autocomplete controls.

```
<input name="someValue"
       #someValueField="ngModel"
       [(ngModel)]="someValue"
       [matAutocomplete]="someValueAutocomplete" />
<mat-autocomplete #someValueAutocomplete="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of collection | filterCollection:{mode: 'contains', property: 'name', value: someValue}"
               [value]="item.id">
     {{ item.name }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**The Problem**
I'm wanting to refactor the object that appears on line 5 of my above example into an object that hangs off of the component, like so:

```
// import statements

@Component(
  selector: 'app-my-awesome-component',
  templateUrl: './my-awesome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-awesome.component.scss']
)
export class MyAwesomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public someValue: string = '';
  public collection: {id: number, name: string}[] = [];
  // This is what I'd like to send to the pipe...
  public filteringCondition = {
    mode: 'contains',
    property: 'name',
    value: this.someValue
  };

  public constructor() {}
  public onInit(): void {
    // Pull collection items from the database; irrelevant implementation to question.
  }

  // Methods and stuff are similarly irrelevant.
}
```

...Which would make my markup look like this:

```
<input name="someValue"
       #someValueField="ngModel"
       [(ngModel)]="someValue"
       [matAutocomplete]="someValueAutocomplete" />
<mat-autocomplete #someValueAutocomplete="matAutocomplete">
   <!-- Refactor is below!  "filterCollection"'s parameter should now be the filteringCondition object from the component... -->
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of collection | filterCollection:filteringCondition"
               [value]="item.id">
     {{ item.name }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

If I set my autocompletes up as I show in the background example, where I'm hard-coding the object into the `*ngFor` attribute value, then the filter works correctly.  However, when I refactor the code to look like it does immediately above this paragraph, the filter stops working.

**Question**
Is it possible to pass a complex object to a filter, as I would like to do for my refactor, or am I restricted to hard-coding a filter condition object directly in the `*ngFor` attribute?

If it is possible, the follow-up question is: what's the right way to do it?

Comment: You should be able to pass any object. [See here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbar77?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-pipe.pipe.ts). I can't see why it's not working for you. Can you confirm if you are getting the object within the pipe by logging it?

Comment: I updated my code to show what I'm doing more accurately; I didn't add the fact that I'm passing values from the controller as part of the pipe parameters.  In fact, the more I think about it, the more I'm sure that passing the value of an input as part of the pipe parameters is where the problem is.  By way of patiently commenting, you may have just helped me figure out what's up this particular case.

I probably need to put the spec object in a `BehaviorSubject<>` or something and rig up a `(change)` event if I wanted to refactor it as I'm trying to do...

Comment: ...which now that you make me think of it, I'm not so sure I do.  The cosmetic simplicity probably isn't worth the increased maintenance cost that such a refactor would create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only changing a property on the `filteringCondition` object and not the object itself. When binding to variables in the template, Angular's change detection will only detect the change if the reference of that variable changes. In other words, if you create a new `filteringCondition` object every time `this.someValue` changes, then your code should work again. Take a look at [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbar77?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).